# LocalDB- master database , backup/restore feature

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, localdb

I have a C#,.net application which connects to a SQLexpress database.

I am changing the database to localDB.Now there are couple features like

1. Database restore/backup - i have a common stored procedure in master and i call that for the same.
2. get all databases in the server instance

for both of them the connection string is something like

```
 "Data Source=ConfiguarionDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"
```

But since i am moving to localdb , what should be the connection string ?

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;AttachDbFileName= D:\\ConfiguarionDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"
```

which doesn't work!. I am able to load the database and perform all other operations which doesn't involve master db(ofcourse connection string doesn't involve master db)

Comment: Your given connection string for localdb having unwanted semicolan(;) at the end.

Comment: changed now .. but thats not the problem

Comment: Isn't an MDF File a single DB? If so, wouldn't there be a different MSF for the MASTER? I don't know locvaldb: does it even have a master DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try your connection string without using **Initial Catalog**. Like this

"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=D:\ConfiguarionDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"